# Not able to fill expiry Dates Text Field using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Site: https://music.apple.com

Below is my code:

```
Exp = "032025"
for i in Exp:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="expiration"]').send_keys(i)
    time.sleep(0.40)
```

With the code above, it fills the expiry as 02/3025 rather than 03/2025

One temporary way of making it work is by changing the expiry to 023025, i know i am being funny. I need a real fix for when which it should work even with a list of expiries to loop from.

PS: I tried using loop because with just send_keys(Exp) i wasnt able to fill the Expiry field

Comment: where is that  `expiration` on the web page ?

Comment: Please add relevant HTML code, at least from my country I do not see element with XPath //*[@id="expiration"]

Comment: Hi @cruisepandey
It asks expiration when you try to add a VCC to claim the free apple music trial

Comment: Hi @K.B. 
thanks for commenting but It was mentioned above in the question ,that i am able to fill the expiration date which means that the xpath exists.
Pls check once again , you should see it when you are being asked to enter the VCC details.